# My .png image PUT request into an AWS S3 bucket is appearing as text

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

I am attempting to upload publicly viewable photos browser-side to an S3 Bucket.  I am using a server to authenticate my request and give the browser a signed URL.  My PUT statement works and my S3 Bucket will have a new object added to it. The metadata is coming in with "Content-Type" : 
application/json;charset=UTF-8. Even though I am setting it to 'image/png' in my code.  Additionally even if I change the metadata to 'image/png' when I go to the url to view my image I see a long string of text which was the data that represents the image something like this "["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASQAAAEjCAYAAACb/HxUA] which continues for around 26,000 characters.

Why is the page displaying text and not an image?

Here is my browser code for the request:

```
axios.get('/picture', {params: { filename: `${this.props.user.id}_${Date.now()}`}})
        .then(response =>{
            var signedUrl = response.data;
            var headers= {
                   'ACL': 'public-read',
                  'Content-Type': this.state.imageType,
                };

            return axios.put(signedUrl, this.state.imgSrc, headers);
        })
```

The first `axios.get` is a request to get the signed url.

Here is the server code to create the signed url.

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
region: 'us-east-2',
accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
```

});

```
router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    let params = {
        Bucket: 'beerphotos',
        Key: req.query.filename,
        //Body : req.query.picture[0],
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: 'image/png',
        Expires: 60,
    }
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error Getting Signed URL', err);
            return err;
        } else {
            console.log('This is the data', data)
            res.send(data);
        }
    })

})
```

Comment: what is the value of `this.state.imgSrc` ?  Looks like your parameter to the PUT call is a text (the base64 encoding of your image : `"["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASQAAAEjCAYAAACb/HxUA]`) instead of a binary

Comment: It is the long string of text that is appearing on the web page. It begins with [“data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0 and then continues for about 26000 characters more.

Comment: This is a string, not an image.  You're asking S3 to store a base64 string of the image instead of an array of bytes.  Maybe these posts can help you to find how to access the bytes of the image.  https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-set-up-simple-image-upload-with-node-and-aws-s3-84e609248792 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I am able to display the image on the page using <img src=this.state.imgSrc > not sure if that is relevant. I will look over that web page!